# Method to scan a network for my devices

Tags: networking, router, ip, lan

Lets assume the following situation.

I have developed a device from which a large number are connected to a LAN. I also have a PC tool to communicate with each of these devices by knowing the IP addresses. Now these devices are obtaining the IP configuration dynamically by DHCP. So I need to scan the network to get information of all the connected devices and list them in my PC tool where I can chose each of them and connect to it.

First idea I had was to send a UDP broadcast message into the subnet where the PC is connected and all of my devices answer with their IP configuration and the PC-Tool lists them for the user to chose the desired one.
This method might be good as long as the PC and the devices are in one subnet. But how do I scan for my devices that are in other subnets behind the gateway?

Are there any possibilities to get information about the network topology and send broadcasts to subnets behind a gateway?

Will there be another way to get the information of the connected devices?

Comment: Have a look at `nmap` (or it's GUI version - `zenmap` https://nmap.org/zenmap/). It should do the trick for you.

Comment: Change your device to automatically register to a management server possibly using some kind of SRV record from the DNS system. Use a multicast address for that kind of communication or if you have to scan the network use something like the already mentioned `nmap`.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar to Seth but using DHCP to serve an extra setting of the IP address of the management platform. Check out DHCP option 43.